# Reflection Map of specified interface

Tags: java, reflection, dictionary

I want to create class map via reflection. How to tell java reflection that I need only implementations of some interface?

I need something like this:

```
public interface Interface {}
public class InterfaceImpl1 implements Interface {}
public class InterfaceImpl2 implements Interface {}
public class Main {
    private static Map<Class<Interface>, String> classMap = new HashMap();
    static {
        classMap.put(InterfaceImpl1.class, "impl1"); // <- Compiler says it's an error
        classMap.put(InterfaceImpl2.class, "impl2"); // <- Also an error :(
    }
}
```

I want to add some kind of typing and polymorphism to reflections. How it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard to indicate that you want any subtype of `Interface`.

```
private static Map<Class<? extends Interface>, String> classMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot of my time :)